# Can you push to a pull request branch in Concourse?

Tags: git, concourse

In Concourse we are using `teliaoss/github-pr-resource` to run pull request checks when a pull request has been created in Github. One of the checks we do is `npm run prettier:fix` which ensures all code is formatted to standards. If the repository shows changes then the task fails and the user has to run the command locally and push changes. This is fine, but we'd love to run `npm run prettier:fix` and then commit the changes to the pull request branch and avoid requiring the user to make another commit.

The git resource is available and allows you to push to a repository, but you have to specify the branch in your yaml, I'm not aware of a way to make that dynamic. Here's a simplified example using the git resource

```
resource_types:
  - name: pull-request
    type: registry-image
    source:
      repository: teliaoss/github-pr-resource

resources:
- name: deployment-plan
  type: git
  source:
    branch: main # this needs to be the pull-request branch
    uri: ((git-base-uri))/myproject

- task: run-prettier
  config:
    platform: linux
    image_resource:
      type: registry-image
      source:
        repository: alpine/git
    inputs:
      - name: deployment-plan
    outputs:
      - name: deployment-plan-git-update
    run:
      path: sh
      args:
        - -exc
        - |
          git clone deployment-plan deployment-plan-git-update
          cd deployment-plan-git-update
          npm run prettier:fix
          git add .
          if [[ ! -z "$(git status --porcelain)" ]]; then
            git commit -m "run prettier"
          fi
  - put: deployment-plan
    params:
      repository: deployment-plan-git-update
    rebase: true
```

Comment: Food for thought: maybe requiring the user to do it themselves will help them learn to conform to the standards. The more annoying it is for them to have to go back and fix it, the more likely they are to follow the standard to begin with. (Not sure if you care about that or not- maybe this is some contrived scenario where all the developers dislike the standard a specific client demands, and they don't want to change their settings for when they work on that client's code...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to explicitly set your branch, but the answer from @Busches got me on the right path

```
- task: prettier
  config:
    platform: linux
    image_resource:
      type: docker-image
      source:
        repository: image-with-node-git-and-jq
        tag: 14
    inputs:
    - name: pull-request
    outputs:
      - name: pull-request
    params:
      USERNAME: ((access-token.username))
      ACCESS_TOKEN: ((access-token.git-access-token))
    run:
      path: sh
      dir: pull-request
      args:
      - -exc
      - |
        export NG_CLI_ANALYTICS=false

        prNumber=$(cat .git/resource/metadata.json | jq -r '.[] | select(.name=="pr") | .value')
        branchName=$(curl 'https://'${USERNAME}:${ACCESS_TOKEN}'@github.nwie.net/api/v3/repos/Nationwide/roundup/pulls/'${prNumber} | jq -r '.head.ref')

        git fetch
        git checkout ${branchName}

        # run any commands that change files here
        npm install -g prettier
        npm run prettier:fix

        git add .

        # only commit if there are changes otherwise the step fails
        if [[ ! -z "$(git status --porcelain)" ]]; then
          git commit -m "prettier fix"

          git push --set-upstream origin ${branchName}
        else
          echo "no changes found"
        fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible pushing straight to the git repo, assuming you've granted your access token user access to the repository.

Here is a rough example:

```
# Run commands to run formatter
if [[ "$(git status -s)" ]]; then
    git commit -m "Formatting Code"
    git push
else
    echo "No changes"
fi
```

Note: in our repo we had to get creative with the `git push` and resetting origin and pushing to the correct branch. The `teliaoss/github-pr-resource` has changed a lot since it was written originally, so hopefully they're not necessary anymore.

Also, since you've now pushed to the PR, this will trigger another build. We worked around this by adding a gate before the PR Build job checking to see if the last commit was the Concourse user with the generated commit message, if it is, then it is skipped and the PR status checks are marked as complete.